# Formula to fulfil 3 conditions

Tags: excel, testing, logic, formula

I’d like some help with a formula that can do the following:

Cell A1 : Participation Type (Leader or Member)
Cell A2 : Full Name
Cell A4 : output cell

1. if cell A1 is empty, return empty in cell A4
2. if cell A1 is not empty, and cell A1 has "Leader", return A2 + (Leader)
3. if cell A1 is not empty, and cell A1 does not have "Leader", return A2 in cell A4

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Cell A4 should have the following formula:

```
=IF(A1="";"";IF(A1="Leader";A2&" Leader";A2))
```

Formula explained:

`IF(A1="";""` means if A1 is empty, then show an empty string.

Otherwise, the rest of the formula applies:

```
IF(A1="Leader";A2&" Leader";A2)
```

This means that, if cell A1 contains the string Leader, show the contents of cell A2 with " Leader" concatenated at the end (notice the leading space to avoid the name and string from being a single word). Otherwise, just show the content of cell A2.